# john the ripper, usages

Tags: passwords

As evident from the site of john the ripper, JTR [example](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/EXAMPLES.shtml), john can be used for finding password form a unix machine `passwd` file.

can JtR be used to crack password of a password encrypted word file? I know there is another utility by openwall which does the same...

Comment: I'm closing this as off topic for the moment - we don't really handle "what can I do with this tool" - for topics that are on topic, have a nosey at the [faq](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq). I've talked to some potential sites about migration; if you have a specific problem you you're interested in understanding if John the Ripper can help with, do feel free to edit the question and flag it and then they'd be happy to have it - there's an edit link under your question and a flag one too :)

Comment: At best this would be on topic on security.SE or superuser. But currently it's far too broad.

Comment: okay...thx anyway... i didn't knew about security.SE...will repost it der...

Comment: @Ninefingers: can you migrate this to security.SE?? or should i repost it?

Comment: @VineetMenon I can migrate it, but I did ask them and I think they'd want it focusing on a more specific problem first :) But when you're done with editing, yes, can migrate no probs.

Comment: Putting it back on zero as there was clearly no ill intent, it's closed anyway...